# Xunit support in sonarqube

Tags: nunit, sonarqube, xunit

Using the following file, I get no results in sonarqube for Xunit tests -output to NUnit style. I cannot see how to get XUnit style working.

```
sonar.projectKey=Checkout
sonar.projectName=CheckOut
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=Program.sln
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=C:\dev\opencoverresults.xml
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=C:\dev\xunitnunit.xml
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is yet to be implemented:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-18

Comment: Looks like this has now been implemented http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772 and https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-18

Comment: this uses msbuild.exe do you know if dotnet command is supported?